# iOS Table View Error - deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it - DGElasticPullToRefresh

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

So I have two UIViewControllers each with a table view in each. The first one has a button to display the second view controller. The second view controller has a button that dismisses the view controller so it goes back to the first one. When I click on the dismiss button in the second view controller it goes back to the first view controller briefly then crashes. The console prints the following error message.

`An instance of class UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it`

I'm not really sure where to start looking because I'm not sure what section the problem is in. I've never had this error before and it doesn't make sense at all since I'm not using any `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer`. I'm not even really aware of any `observers` I'm using.

I'm presenting the view with the following code.

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let menuViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Menu") as UIViewController
self.present(menuViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

And dismissing the view controller with the following code.

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {});
```

What does this error mean? And what would be causing it? All the answers I have seen on stack overflow use code that I don't have anything even remotely similar to, which is why I'm very confused.

I'm pretty sure based on my research it has something to do with one of my table views but I could be totally wrong.

Comment: I'd start by reviewing [these relevant search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+was+deallocated+while+key+value+observers+were+still+registered+with+it).

Comment: Most of those questions I have found include adding an observer to like the UITableViewCell or something along those lines. I'm not sure how I can remove an observer when I didn't add one and when I have no idea what the key path is. I mean I found this `removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")` code but I'm not sure what the key path would be or where I'd put it. Like I'm assuming it'd go in the UITableViewCell `deinit` method. Things still don't add up it seems like.

Comment: You are doing something in viewWillAppear? from the first controller?

Comment: @JoséNeto Nope. Neither of the view controllers have viewWillAppear. Only viewDidLoad.

Comment: Where are you using the dismiss func?

Comment: @JoséNeto In an IBAction linked to a button on the second view controller. Right once I click it it goes back to the first view controller for a brief second then crashes, and prints that message in the console.

Comment: Did you tried to use that in the firstViewController? Because i think it shouldn't work in the second one

Comment: @JoséNeto No. The first view controller has an IBAction linked to a button to present the second view controller. Then the second view controller has a button to dismiss itself and go back to the first view controller. Dismissing the first view controller won't work because there isn't really anything to go back to or anything like that.

Comment: No you use the firstViewController to dismiss the secondViewController, you can use delegate to do it, just test like that and see if works

Comment: I'm not following. How would this look in code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After doing some more research I found that adding the following code to my second view controller solved the problem.

```
deinit {
    self.tableView.dg_removePullToRefresh()
}
```

This is because I'm using a library ([DGElasticPullToRefresh](https://github.com/gontovnik/DGElasticPullToRefresh)) to handle pull to refresh. The GitHub issue regarding this can be found [here](https://github.com/gontovnik/DGElasticPullToRefresh/issues/5). Hopefully this helps someone else having a similar issue or something like that.

Comment: I had to take an extra step of keeping a second, strong reference, to the table view. I was using an IBOutlet and I think that got deallocated before deinit was called.